# Trouble converting string to integer in Python

Tags: python

Forgive me, I am stuck again. I have the following data in string format (sample):

```
389    10 
390     4 
391    10 
392     1 
393     6 
394       
395     3 
396     1
```

I have tried to convert it to integer, but I get:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I assume I have problems with missing values. When I try:

```
df['emp_length'].fillna('0', inplace=True)
```

None of the missing values are replaced with 0. Any thoughts? I am on Python 3.6 (Anaconda). Many thanks!

Comment: Please share the code implementation for converting.

Comment: Am guessing you are trying to convert the whole string line-wise, which contains `whitespace` too. Hence the `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '`

Comment: Try `df.loc[df['emp_length'] == '', 'emp_length'] = 0` then try the int conversion. Does that work?

Comment: Apologies for forgetting to include code for conversion. The solution by roganjosh worked. Thank you!